# index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cat_id'

Tags: python, django

Учусь по книге "Django Практика" Владимир Дронов. И вот застрял на примере, где он выводит список моделей на веб страницу. Объясняет сжато, код относительно понятен, но вот запнулся....

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from lesson.models import Category, Good, Client

def index(request, cat_id):
   cats=Category.objects.all().order_by('name')
   if cat_id ==None:
      cat=Category.objects.first()
   else:
      cat = Category.objects.get(pk=cat_id)

   goods=Good.objects.filter(category=cat).order_by('name')
   return cat_id, render(request, "index.html", {'category':cat, "cats":cats, "goods":goods})
```

**urls.py**

```
from lesson import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('goods/', views.index),
]
```

я все же подозреваю, что он забыл указать что то, либо я что то пропустил... либо разница в версиях самого Django, все же книга 2016 года....
Но вот я не могу вывести html страничку со списком товаров. при чем как я понял, что при клике на какую то из ссылок должна открываться страничка с адресом : `path('goods/<int:cat_id>', views.index),`

но я все получаю ошибку : index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cat_id'

Направьте пожалуйста в нужное русло...

стек с ошибкой :

```
[27/Apr/2022 14:24:20] "GET /goods HTTP/1.1" 301 0
Internal Server Error: /goods/
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File 
 "C:\Users\artiom.oriol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File 
"C:\Users\artiom.oriol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)
TypeError: index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cat_id'
[27/Apr/2022 14:24:20] "GET /goods/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59421
```

Да, я пытался так сделать,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('goods/<int:cat_id>', views.index),
]
```

но он все равно не выводит мне список "категорий" и "товаров" и вот так я тоже пытался вывести:

```
def index(request, cat_id=None):
```

Но затем я получаю:

```
AttributeError at /goods/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/goods/
 Django Version:    4.0.4
 Exception Type:    AttributeError
 Exception Value:   
 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location:  
C:\Users\artiom.oriol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py, line 27, in process_response
Python Executable:   
C:\Users\artiom.oriol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.10
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\artiom.oriol\\Documents\\DjangoProjects\\lessons',
'C:\Users\artiom.oriol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip', 'C:\Users\artiom.oriol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs', 'C:\Users\artiom.oriol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib', 'C:\Users\artiom.oriol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39', 'C:\Users\artiom.oriol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages'] Server time: Wed, 27 Apr 2022 12:05:27 +0000
```

Эту ошибку.

Я так же сделал модели и импортировал их :

```
from lesson.models import Category, Good, Client
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Comment: В функции `def index(request, cat_id):` у вас параметр `cat_id`, а откуда он возьмется? :)

Comment: Дополнил ответ с новыми вводными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас функция требует аргумента *cat_id*, а url его не передает.

Можно его добавить например вот так:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('goods/<int:cat_id>', views.index),
]
```

Альтернативный (*и дополнительный*) вариант - сделать фунцию **index** с аргументом *cat_id* "по умолчанию".

Например так:

```
def index(request, cat_id=None):
```

К тому, же у Вас зачем то функция возвращает **tuple**

```
return cat_id, render(request, "index.html", {'category':cat, "cats":cats, "goods":goods})
```

Должно быть как то так:

```
return render(request, "index.html", {'category':cat, "cats":cats, "goods":goods})
```

Comment: .....Я свой мозг топтал.....это что за невнимательность.....   Спасибо за то что открыли глаза.... иду в угол стыдиться....